# ApplicationBar Working Different in Windows Phone 7 Beta Than CTP

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mobile, windows-phone-7

There are a few issues I notice with the beta version of the WP7 tools:

- The ApplicationBar no longer causes a page to resize it contents with the CTP workaround
- Using the ApplicationBar from App.xaml and imported as a static resource does not work as expected

In the CTP version of the WP7 tools when using an appbar and navigation from page to page, the appbar remainined on top of the page content rather than having the content resize itself to be on top of the appbar.  The work around was to set the IsVisible property to false in the constructor and set to true on the page loaded event.  This is no longer working and the appbar remains on top of the loaded page unless turned completely off.  I have my appbar xaml in app.xaml and each page uses it as a static resource.

Also the click event is no longer triggered for app buttons, I am using the appbar as a resource in my App.xaml and added as a {StaticResource} in my page's xaml.  Any help would be appreciated as this is the only way I have for navigating around my application, aside from rolling my own navigation page.

```
public CalculatorView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;

    SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait;

    Application.Current.RootVisual = this;
}

private void PhoneApplicationPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
}
```

AppBar XAML:

```
<Shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="GlobalApplicationBar" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
    <Shell:ApplicationBar.Buttons>
        <Shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="CalculaterAppIconButton" Click="CalculaterMenuItemClick" IconUri="/Images/Icons/32/Back.png" Text="Main" />
        <Shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="HistoryAppIconButton" Click="HistoryMenuItemClick" IconUri="/Images/Icons/32/Intl-History.png" Text="History" />
        <Shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="StatisticsAppIconButton" Click="StatisticsMenuItemClick" IconUri="/Images/Icons/32/Stats.png" Text="Stats" />
        <Shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="OptionsAppIconButton" Click="OptionsMenuItemClick" IconUri="/Images/Icons/32/Settings.png" Text="Options" />
    </Shell:ApplicationBar.Buttons>
    <Shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        <Shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="StartingHandsMenuItem" Click="StartingHandsMenuItemClick" Text="Starting Hands" />
        <Shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="HoleOddsMenuItem" Click="HoleOddsMenuItemClick" Text="Hole Odds" />
    </Shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
</Shell:ApplicationBar>
```

AppBar in Phone Application Page:

```
ApplicationBar="{StaticResource GlobalApplicationBar}"   //In my page.xaml
```

Comment: It sounds a bit like you found a way to make the app bar behave in a non-standard way in the CTP version but that no longer works? However I'm not certain I understand what you mean when you say stays on top.

To your second point - when I try using an app bar as a static resource I find the event handlers are called as expected.

Comment: By top I mean an overlay, the app bar is drawn last so it covers the window contents underneath.  Here's a link to what it looks like:

http://cid-66e5fcb98f941ac7.photos.live.com/self.aspx/Public/AppBar-Overlay.jpg 

Notice that the border should be resized so that it occupies the top part of the screen.

Second clicking any button in the appbar does nothing but show an animation.

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the fact you are refering to perceived differences between the Beta and CTP versions of the tools.
The ApplicationBar appear over the top of the page content based on it's opacity:

> If the opacity is set to 1, the
>   displayed page will be resized to be
>   the area of the screen not covered by
>   the Application Bar.

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431806%28VS.92%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  This is an old post and I believe the RTW fixes the issue.

Comment: @JPM I'm aware it's an old issue but wanted to make sure there was a response in case anyone else with a similar issue found this.